# javascript login validation

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a javascript function that is called on submit.

```
<script>
function validateLogin() {
    var x = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
    var y = document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
    if (x == "" && y == "") {
        alert("Please enter an email and password!");
    } else if (x == "") {
        alert("Please enter an email!");
    } else if (y == "") {
        alert("Please enter a password!");
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

And is called like so `onsubmit="return validateLogin()"`

The function works fine however when the alert appears and you click okay, the page refreshes. Is there a way too stop it refreshing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to `return false;` to stop form submission and page redirection, when error occurs.
2. No need of last `else`
3. `trim` username value

Code:

```
<script>
function validateLogin() {
    var x = document.forms["login"]["username"].value.trim();
    var y = document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
    if (x == "" && y == "") {
        alert("Please enter an email and password!");
        return false; // Here
    } else if (x == "") {
        alert("Please enter an email!");
        return false; // Here
    } else if (y == "") {
        alert("Please enter a password!");
        return false; // Here
    }
}
</script>
```

I'll also suggest you to use HTML-5 `required` attribute for required fields.

```
<form name="login">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" required />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" required />
</form>
```

Comment: +1 for the advice on html5 and the required attribute. In combination with the html5 constraint validation api the topic starter should be able to solve his problem more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateLogin() {
  var x = document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
  var y = document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
  if (x == "" && y == "") {
    alert("Please enter an email and password!");
return false;
   } else if (x == "") {
    alert("Please enter an email!");
    return false;
   } else if (y == "") {
    alert("Please enter a password!");
    return false;
   }
}
```